# How can I get the name of the database server from within a stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm making complete connection strings inside my procedure and would like to inject the name of the database server in them. Is there any way that I can detect the name from inside or am I doomed to passing it in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [SERVERPROPERTY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174396.aspx):

- `SERVERPROPERTY('MachineName')`: name of the SQL Server host name, cluster aware
- `SERVERPROPERTY('ComputerNamePhysicalNetBIOS')`: name of physical machine name. In a cluster, is the name of the current active node. On a standalone instalation, is identical with MachineName
- `SERVERPROPERTY('InstanceName')`: name of the current SQL Server instance. NULL for default.

One thing I'd recomend **against** is the dreaded @@SERVERNAME. This property is notorious for getting out of sync with reality after a machine rename. I've seen way too many apps burned by this problem to place any trust on it. The correct rename procedure is in BOL, but few use it properly: [How to: Rename a Computer that Hosts a Stand-Alone Instance of SQL Server](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143799.aspx).

Comment: Sweet! You're right @@SERVERNAME didn't give me the right value. Small follow up: if I want to append the domain name to the end of the server name would I have to loop through all the AD domains and pick the one I want or is there an easier way if there is only one?

Comment: I actually had the very same problem recently and could not find a reasonable solution. I ended up adding a CLR function to the database that was returning the DNS suffix from the Network interface info, like http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ipinterfaceproperties.dnssuffix(VS.85).aspx.

Answer (score 2):

So for MS SQL Server you could:

```
SELECT @@SERVERNAME
```

For MySQL, it's

```
SELECT variable_value as servername
FROM information_schema.global_variables
WHERE variable_name = 'hostname';
```

For Oracle, its:

```
SELECT global_name FROM global_name
```